# Android Map with current location

Tags: android, gps

i have got the following codes but my gps is not getting the current location, showing me the address on touch and no overlay. I got the latitude and longitude as 0.0. Basically only the map is showing up. Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

> public class Map extends MapActivity{

```
MapView mapView;
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
private LocationManager lm;
private LocationListener locationListener;
Button btn_send;
int lat, lng;


class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        //---add the marker---
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.pin);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
    {   
        //---when user lifts his finger---
        if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault()); 
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                        p.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                        p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                    String add = "";
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                    {
                        for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); 
                             i++)
                           add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {                
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                return true;
            }
            else                
                return false;
    }
} 


  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        MapController mc = mapView.getController(); 
        switch (keyCode) 
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
                mc.zoomIn();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                mc.zoomOut();
                break;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }    


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

    Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

                Intent new_intent = new Intent("net.learn2develop.SendSMS");
                startActivity(new_intent);
        }
    });

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
    String latitude = Integer.toString(lat);
    String longitude = Integer.toString(lng); 
    String coordinates[] = {latitude, longitude};
    double lati = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lngi = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
    System.out.println("lat" + lati + "lng" + lngi );
    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lati * 1E6), 
        (int) (lngi * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 
    mapView.invalidate();

  //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

    mapView.invalidate();


}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
        System.out.println("lat shld b smth " + lat + "lng smth " +lng);
        //GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        //mc.animateTo(point); //   mapController.setCenter(point);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi user596379, may I obtain the project source code? I am trying to create a prototype for my thesis. Would you share it? Thanks in advanced ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the current location of the user, you might be better off using the MyLocationOverlay. You can also subclass it and override onLocationChanged, to insert custom code.

Enable it by calling enableMyLocation onResume() and disableMyLocation onPause().

Answer (score 0):

It take 2 to 15 minutes to get a satellite GPS fix. You should move the code for rendering the point to `onLocationChanged()`

Comment: did u mean this code i shld move?  //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

Comment: No move everything from "String latitude = Integer.toString(lat);" onwards to 
onLocationChanged()

Comment: i have moved the codes but my application crash now. i got nullpointer as the error. Was it because i need to test on a real phone instead of emulator?

Comment: You never mentioned the emulator in your question. If you are using the emulator there is a ddms setting where you can input a lat, lon or a kml. Secondly always check the location that is obtained in onLocationChanged() for null

Comment: yes. i have input the lat and lon. i did a S.O.P hre  double lati = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
         double lngi = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
         System.out.println("lat" + lati + "lng" + lngi );. But it didn't animate to the place.

Comment: Integer.toString() is wrong, because lat,lon come in Double. Check your math again. Use Log.d() for debugging and read the api documentation. You are asking a lot of questions in the comments. Generally this is not how you use SO.